# Matlab: system call of ImageMagick get forbidden parameter

Tags: matlab, imagemagick, system-calls

I want to call ImageMagick from Matlab (Win, German GUI) but I get in the Command Window an error message "Unzulässiger Parameter - -negate " (forbidden parameter).

```
output_meta_folder = 'D:\D-ART\Abstrakt_ART\CM\';
system_string = strcat('convert', [' ', output_meta_folder], 'CM_mask.jpg', ' -negate -morphology Thicken Disk:10 -negate ', [' ', output_meta_folder], 'CM_mask_morpho_D10.jpg'); 
disp(system_string);
status = system(system_string);
```

But the command is correct; if I copy the displayed system string and  paste it in the command line I got no error from ImageMagick:

```
convert D:\D-ART\Abstrakt_ART\CM\CM_mask.jpg -negate -morphology Thicken Disk:10 -negate D:\D-ART\Abstrakt_ART\CM\CM_mask_morpho_D10.jpg
```

The error can not be caused by -negate because if I delete the first negate the error message adapted to "Unzulässiger Parameter - -morphology ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Version 7+ of **ImageMagick**, try changing the command `convert` into `magick` as there is a Microsoft program called `CONVERT.EXE` which clashes:

```
magick someFile -negate -morphology ... -negate result.jpg
```

If that doesn't work, try specifying the full path to `convert`, e.g. something like:

```
C:\Programs\ImageMagick-6.9.3\bin\convert ...
```

or try setting the `PATH` environment variable in **Matlab** to include the directory where **ImageMagick** is installed but put that at the very start of your PATH - ahead of `C:\Windows\System32` where the nasty Microsoft `CONVERT.EXE` lurks.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is working: ImageMagick_convert_path = '"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.7-Q8\convert.exe"'; 
system_string = strcat(ImageMagick_convert_path, [' ', output_meta_folder], ....);